# How to make a site in IIS 8 accessible to whole world?

Tags: iis, web, windows-server-2012

I created a site in IIS 8 in windows server 2012, and I want to access it from other computers. Does anyone know how to do this? I can't find any tutorials using IIS 8 anywhere with detailed instructions.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with other versions of IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the site from anywhere in the world, you will have to do two things,

1) Use a static IP on your computer, This guide should help: http://www.sysads.co.uk/2013/01/assign-a-static-ip-address-to-windows-server-2012/

2) Enable port forwarding on your router to your static IP: Use this guide:
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

Go there,  select your router and model. And when it asks you to pick an Application, select Apache (since there is no IIS). It's the same setup procedure.

That's it, now goto http://www.whatismyip.com/, Copy your IP address, paste it in the address bar (on a PC/Mobile/Tablet using a different router (like at a friends house :D )), and you should be able to see your site! :D you can enter that IP address on any computer in the world, and itll show your site.

Oh, wait. I almost forgot... ISPs tend to change your IP address often. Meaning later on, that IP address won't link to your site anymore. Youll have to goto http://www.whatismyip.com/ again get the new IP address.

If you don't want it to change, contact your ISP and tell them you want a Static IP. This always costs though.

Now if you wan't someone to visit your site using a domain, instead of your IP address. Go ahead and register a domain. Google "domain registration" and find a plan that suits you. :D

Personally however, If it's a small scale solution, it's cheaper to just get a hosting plan. Plus, they've got the right Hardware, Software and support! :D

Happy hosting!

Comment: I am going though this now, but how do I find my `IP address of your primary domain controller`?

Comment: Oh, that's basically your DNS. Either use the one for your ISP (google it) or a better solution (What I do) is to use google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Those are the Primary and Alternate DNS servers